# Solution for removing duplicate Chrome bookmarks

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, bookmarks

My Chrome bookmarks keep duplicating and old ones previously deleted last year are back.  Are there any suggestions on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question is missing a lot of info.  You can see [ask] for important info on asking questions on this site.

Comment: Besides missing info as indicated by @fsb, "Best Fix" is asking for opinions which is off topic.  Duplicating bookmarks leans much more toward being a Chrome issue rather than a macOS issue - what research have you done with respect to that?  It would be a good idea to review [What Questions can I ask about](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for assistance.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Apple hardware or software?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, the OP indicated they’re on a MacBook Pro and software that runs on Apple products is technically on topic. We’re just missing too many details.